# Sending size of buffer through pipe from process to process

Tags: c, process, pipe

I have created two child processes with a pipe connection between them.

Code in process A:

```
char *buf;
size_t size;

buf = "some string";
size = strlen(buf);
printf("size in process A:%zu\n", size);
write(pfds[3][1], &size, sizeof (size_t));
write(pfds[3][1], buf, sizeof (buf));


buf="other string";
size = strlen(buf);
printf("size in process A:%zu\n", size);
write(pfds[3][1], &size, sizeof (size_t));
write(pfds[3][1], buf, sizeof (buf));
```

Code in process B:

```
size_t size;
/*read in size from Process A*/
read(pfds[3][0], &size, sizeof (size_t));
printf("READ size in process B: %zu\n", size);

/*allocate memory space for the line*/
char *buf = malloc(size);

/*read in line from process A*/
read(pfds[3][0], buf, size);
printf("READ buf in process B: %s.\n", buf);

/*read in size from readProcess*/
read(pfds[3][0], &size, sizeof (size_t));
printf("READ size in process B:%zu\n", size);

/*free the allocated memory*/
free(buf);
```

The output looks like this:

```
size in process A:11
size in process A:12
READ size in process B: 11
READ buf in process B: some
                            .
READ size in process B:101
```

I want to use the size to control a while loop to continuously send lines from A to B, until the size becomes 0. But what am I doing wrong? The size is right the first time it is sent, but not the second time.

Comment: Why you need to pass the number of lines to process? Can't you read until the last line? In case you need it you may print the size with fprintf and then read it back with fscanf.

Comment: @Adriano I don't want to pass the number of lines, I want to pass the length of each line so I can allocate memory for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sizof(buf) will return 4, the size of a pointer, What you need is strlen(buf)
so

> write(pfds[3][1], buf, sizeof (buf));

should be

> write(pfds[3][1], buf, strlen(buf));

Comment: +1, though not exacly. If you're sending strings, you need to send the terminating NUL character, so pass strlen(buf) + 1 instead.